# How to parse values for the result set's .equals function?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

[image showing my jFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBWJs.png)

I am making a frame which shows records in the sql table one-by-one using text fields as shown. While writing the code for the next button, I need to know the position of the result set to go to the next record. For this purpose, I used a do-while loop with an "if" condition. Following is my code:

```
try{
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYORG", userid="root", pwd="shreyansh";
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid,pwd);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String query="select * from emp;";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        String search=jTextField1.getText();
        String search1=jTextField2.getText();
        double search2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
        String search3=jTextField3.getText();
        rs.first();
        do{
            if(rs.equals(new Object[] {search, search1, search2, search3}))
                break;
        }while(rs.next());
        rs.next();
        String nm=rs.getString("Name");
        String desg=rs.getString("Designation");
        double pay=rs.getDouble("Pay");
        String city=rs.getString("City");
        jTextField1.setText(nm);
        jTextField2.setText(desg);
        jTextField3.setText(pay + "");
        jTextField4.setText(city);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
```

But it shows an error "after end of Result Set".
Please help me with this.
Any suggestions to make my code better are also welcome.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `rs.equals` if for comparing two result sets. Whatever this might actually mean, it's not going to consider an array of objects as equal to a result set.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace. Why are you calling `rs.first()` (and ignoring its return value)? In the current logic, you are looping until `rs.next()` returns false and then call `getString`, which is not allowed as the result set will be positioned **after** the last row. If you want to check for existence in the database of certain values use a `where`-clause.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks a lot for your response!! Actually I am a student. I am a learner but according to me, I placed the pointer of ResultSet at the start of the table using rs.first(), and started comparing it with the existing values in the text Fields until it found he correct match. As I found the correct match, I broke the loop and came out of it and used rs.next() as it is the code for the "Next" button. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks a lot for your response!! I couldn't get quite clearly what you mean to say. Do you mean that rs.equals() won't compare the existing values of a result set to an Object? How can I compare it then? Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't normally call `rs.first()`, it is only guaranteed to work on scrollable result sets. You should normally use only `rs.next()` (eg in a while-loop). Your code isn't finding the correct match because what you do simply doesn't work, so you exit the loop when `rs.next()` returns false.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried doing it without rs.first(), with a while loop too. But it still didn't work. Gives the same error :  "after end of Result Set"

Comment: That is because _"Your code isn't finding the correct match because what you do simply doesn't work"_ If you want to search for rows in a table **use a where-clause**, do not retrieve all rows and filter in your Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ResultSet.equals` for this, because that is not what the [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) contract is for. It is for checking if an object is equal to another object of the same (or at least compatible) type. A `ResultSet` will therefor never be equal to an array of object values.

It looks like you want to select a single row from the `emp` table that matches your search values, in that case the correct solution is to ask the database for only that row. Selecting all rows and then filtering in your Java application is very inefficient, because the database has to send all rows to your application, while finding data is exactly what a database is good at.

Instead, you should use a where clause with a prepared statement:

```java
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, pwd);
     PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
         "select * from emp where Name = ? and Designation = ? and Pay = ? and City = ?")) {
   pstmt.setString(1, search);
   pstmt.setString(2, search1);
   pstmt.setDouble(3, search2);
   pstmt.setString(4, search3);
   try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
       if (rs.next() {
           String nm = rs.getString("Name");
           String desg = rs.getString("Designation");
           double pay = rs.getDouble("Pay");
           String city = rs.getString("City");
           jTextField1.setText(nm);
           jTextField2.setText(desg);
           jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(pay));
           jTextField4.setText(city);
       } else {
           // handle not found case
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: @ShreyanshTiwari In that case, please accept the answer.